# How to display two different classes in a widgets in qt form designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

I have a form with two widgets on it. I want to display a different svg image in each of the widgets using QSvgRenderer. I have two different classes which can display the svg image, but as soon as i promote the two classes to both widgets, i get this error ->

[image]

But if i promote only one class to a widget or the same class to both widgets, everything is oke and i dont get errors. Its like somehow the second class kills the other. But i don't understand what exactly i am doing wrong.

**displaychart.h**:

```
#ifndef DISPLAYWIDGET_H
#define DISPLAYWIDGET_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QHash>
#include <QWidget>

//! [DisplayWidget class definition]
class displaychart : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    displaychart(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter &painter);

    public slots:

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

    private:

 };
 #endif
```

And displaychart.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "displaychart.h"

#include <QSvgRenderer>

displaychart::displaychart(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{

}


void displaychart::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    //Create qpainter object
    QPainter painter(this);

    // file location main wheel in qstring
    QString svgFile = "/home/arjan/qtprojects/astro/AstroQt/svg/natalwheel.svg";

    // create svg object
    QSvgRenderer svgr(svgFile);

    // Render paint object
    svgr.render(&painter);

    // end paint
    painter.end();
}
```

The other class is exactly the same. Only the function names and file names are renamed.

**displayaspect.h:**

```
#ifndef DISPLAYWIDGET_H
#define DISPLAYWIDGET_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QHash>
#include <QWidget>

//! [DisplayWidget class definition]
class displayaspect : public QWidget 
{

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        displayaspect(QWidget *parent = 0);
        void paint(QPainter &painter);

    public slots:

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

    private:
};

#endif
```

**And displayaspect.cpp**:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "displayaspect.h"
#include <QSvgRenderer>

displayaspect::displayaspect(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

}


void displayaspect::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    //Create qpainter object
    QPainter painter(this);

    // file location main wheel in qstring
    QString svgFile = "/home/arjan/qtprojects/astro/AstroQt/svg/natalaspect.svg";

    // create svg object
    QSvgRenderer svgr(svgFile);

    // Render paint object
    svgr.render(&painter);

    // end paint
    painter.end();
}
```

Comment: share the .ui.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely the include guard of the `displaychart.h` file.

Try changing the following...

```
#ifndef DISPLAYWIDGET_H
#define DISPLAYWIDGET_H
```

...into

```
#ifndef DISPLAYCHART_H
#define DISPLAYCHART_H
```

By having the same include guard in both files, you are effectively preventing the compiler from seeing the second class, which results in the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanx! Have been looking for hours at the problem... Turned out that both header files needed a different name. DISPLAYCHART_H and DISPLAYASPECT_H. Now works as expected.